# Can you inject weedbegone into wild violet roots?

Tags: lawn-repair, herbicide

I am trying to complete eradicate the wild violets from my lawn
The soil seems to be a little sandy when it gets dry so they seem to like it a lot
2Y ago I had to completely remove the lawn in order to get rid of them
I did a pretty good job but they are still popping up here and there
Weedbgone dones not seem to hurt them more than temporarily
It seems to me that the herbicide does not get to the roots and kill the plant as it should
Given their relative small number I am considering injecting them one by one to make sure they do not come back. I usually remove them after the rain when the soil is wet and I can stick my finger in and dig the roots out but I do not always succeed so next year they come back

Answer (score 1):

Does the [labeling of the product](https://www.ortho.com/sites/g/files/oydgjc116/files/asset_files/T90408_991511005_LB14611_072320_CFL.pdf) indicate that as an an approved application method? If not, in most civilized countries, no, you can't, at least not legally.

Comment: So what is the legal problem that I am facing if I do that? What are the problems that such a method to apply the product will generate ?

Comment: Applying pesticides not in accordance with their labeling is generally broadly forbidden. I believe you're in Canada, so *"The import, sale or use of unregistered pesticides in Canada is a violation of the Pest Control Products Act, as is using a pesticide in a manner other than directed on the product label."*  https://www.canada.ca/en/health-canada/services/consumer-product-safety/pesticides-pest-management/public/protecting-your-health-environment/compliance-enforcement/enforcement-bulletins.html

Comment: See also: https://cnla.ca/uploads/pdf/Pesticide-Regulation-Across-Canada.pdf